# Only 15 devices in Play store Android / Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play

I'm not sure what is limiting my compatible devices to just 15.  But that seems really very ridiculous for this seemingly standard set of permissions.  Additionally, It looks like I can't take this down to a lower sdk either.  Here is the unpacked manifest from the apk up in the store -- so after the additions that xamarin included after building, archiving and distributing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0" platformBuildVersionCode="26" package="com.crowd_app.tinderdata" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="13" android:versionCode="13" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="25" android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>


<application android:name="md54362bc174d6bb640c83d6fe25c8079c9.MainApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/logo_512x512" android:label="Data for Tinder" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyD1LpusegJbAUXo4uZwCbkS5NDyzaHjOd8"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


<activity android:name="md54362bc174d6bb640c83d6fe25c8079c9.MainActivity" android:label="TinderData">


<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

<provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="com.crowd_app.tinderdata.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:exported="false"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

</application>

<meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you remove `<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>` then give a try ?

Comment: If you aren't trying to absolutely restrict something, don't add in support-XXX tags.  The default is to allow everything. Same for uses-feature

Comment: Hey thanks -- I initially tried it without supports-screens and had the same issue.  So with/without it makes no difference.

Comment: As for the uses-feature, it seems that's added in by xamarin in the build process as it's not apart of my original manifest... so my hands are tied there I think.  Does it even matter in this case considering that "required" is set to false?

Comment: I ended up creating a new application and everything worked fine after republishing and there are now 12k devices that are compatible.  God knows what weird hangup was going on in the google play store.  Anyway, thanks for your help.  Hopefully this was an isolated incident.